# Why my code is showing error since the syntax is right near error keyword

Tags: solidity, blockchain

Error

> ParserError: Expected ';' but got '(' --> me/RevertAndAssert.sol:9:17: | 9 | error throwError() | ^

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract RevertAndAssert {

    address public owner = msg.sender;
    uint public age = 15;

    error FalseAge();

    function checkRevert(uint _x) public {
        age = age + 6;
        if (_x > 20) {
          revert FalseAge();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ParserError: Expected ';' but got '('
--> me/RevertAndAssert.sol:9:17:
|
9 | error throwError()
| ^

Comment: Not an answer but I highly recommend using a code formatter like Prettier. Check out my [Hardhat-based Solidity development template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template), which comes with a Prettier set up pre-configured for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is using an old version that does not support Errors yet.

change to `0.8.7` and it will work. Also, avoid using `^`.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract RevertAndAssert {

    address public owner = msg.sender;
    uint public age = 15;

    error FalseAge();

    function checkRevert(uint _x) public {
        age = age + 6;
        if (_x > 20) {
          revert FalseAge();
        }
    }
}
```